# Is it ok to perform a segue inside a for loop?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, segue

Is it ok to perform a segue in a for loop like below or I am setting myself up for trouble?

Or will it simply perform the segue and the rest of the code is never executed?

```
for(symbol in results) {

            if ([symbol.data hasPrefix:@"--"]) {
                actualBarCodeStr = [symbol.data substringFromIndex:2];
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"trListViewToTrSearchView" sender:self];
            } else {

            createTransactionResult = [NWBarCodeHelper createTransactionRowFromBarCode:symbol.data];

            if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
                NSLog(@"Zbar delegate holds barcode: %@", symbol.data);
                if(createTransactionResult != 0) {
                        NSLog(@"TransactionListView:ZBarDelegate:createTransactionFrombarCode failed with errorCode %i", createTransactionResult);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the segue has no animations, it will probably be fine. With animations the controllers will probably end in undefined state. Still not something you should do.

Comment: So what are my options here? I have to run the for loop to get the data, can I break directly after the performSegue? or what shall I do, set a flag and perform the segue further down in the method? once I have cleared the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code is in a method, they will all run in one runloop even if you have performed the first segue. So all the segue will be performed. If it's just a push, I think there will be a bunch of view controller be pushed. For cases like modal present, I think it may crash but I have not tested it.